# Logging and tracing messages

Tags: logging, spring-ws, spring-amqp, trace

Is it possible to log messages by analogy as it in [Spring ws](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#logging)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring AMQP uses commons-logging too (as do most Spring projects).